# Can ellipsoid or other surface trap incoming light or photon

Tags: geometry, dynamical-systems, billiards

There had already several questions about light-trapping curves, such as [drawing a curve captures light](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008420/can-you-draw-a-curve-that-captures-light) or [photon-trapping curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3283732/photon-trapping-curve), and well known cases had been answered such as [ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4462369/how-to-simplify-the-calculations-of-reflecting-a-ray-about-an-ellipse/4462493#4462493) or [hyperbola](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3284448/11604).

With a proper rotation of ellipse or hyperbola, it is easy to find surface can trap light. Except these case which are 2D cases by nature, can we find some **true** 3D cases which can not reduce the problem to 2D by rotation, mirror operations?

Especially, here I also ask whether a light-trapping path exists in a ellipsoid?

Comment: Each reflection involves two line segments, which by nature must be two-dimensional.  So any case of light-trapping which requires three dimensions must involve at least two reflections simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @abiessu, do you mean that the segments will approach to a plane if light-trapping path exists? But for normal paths, the vertices  scattered in a 3D space. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I'm only considering each pair of light rays around individual reflections, which is a set of strictly two dimensional cases.  There is nothing inherent in that which makes any consideration beyond two dimensions necessary, therefore a minimum of two reflections is required to reach the necessary complexity for three dimensional light trapping schemes.  Yes, real light scatters, but such a consideration might be better suited for the physics stack exchange.